# Restricting group expansion in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder, sql-server-data-tools

I have a requirement where only one grouping may be open at a time, but I was not able to accomplish this with expressions or JavaScript. Any tips/ suggestions are welcome.

Here's a sample image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/odbLR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function which allows you to collapse all the groups at once. Then simply call this function right before you expand the selected group. This will collapse all the groups first and then open the wanted column.

Here is an extremely detailed tutorial explaining [how to collapse and/or expand all the groups at once](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/19/expand-or-collapse-all-grouped-items-on-ssrs-report.html) which you can incorporate on the group header without needing to add extra buttons.